# How to fix top dynamically using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to fix .black below the every `.red` div. If `.red` position changed I want to change top position of `.black` div. Is this possible in css? any JS solution highly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="red">red</div>
<div class="black">black</div>

<div class="red1">red1</div>
<div class="black1">black1</div>

<div class="red2">red2</div>
<div class="black2">black2</div>

<div class="red3">red3</div>
<div class="black3">black3</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position:fixed;
}
}
.red
{
    top: 40px;
}

.red1
{
    top:80px;
}
.red2
{
    top:140px;
}
.red3
{
    top:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you put those two divs inside a new div like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="red">red</div>
    <div class="black">black</div>
</div>
```

And instead of repositioning 'red' you reposition whole this wrap div, in this way both of your divs 'red' & 'black' would be always one under the other one.

Comment: I know it. I want this for some slider funtion.

Comment: Than you have to show us more of your current code so we can help you. Unfortunately like this we can only guess what you need.

Answer (score 0):

**This may help you.**

```
$("div.red").on("change",function(e){
  var position = $(this).position();
  $("div.black").css({"position": position.top + 40});
});
```